# How to get data from this kind of xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContactInfo>
  <info toll_free_phone="(800)471-9933"
        direct_phone="(210)361-9910"
        fax="(210)361-9911"
        email="support@rapidbillpay.com"
        address_line1="2018 I-10 West"
        address_line2=""
        city="San Antonio"
        state="TX"
        zip="78216"/>
</ContactInfo>
```

How do I Access info from such kind of XML data?

In this case, there are no separate elements for each property like

```
<fax>xxxxx</fax>
```

They the values are under single element "info"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In this case data is represented in Attributes instead of elements.

Refer:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

[reading XML attributes in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329878/reading-xml-attributes-in-javascript)